# How can i change progress color from java code?

Tags: css, javafx

I'm trying to make custom properties for progressbar control.I tried to change progressbar color with changing style from java code ,but when i use `setStyle(".bar {-fx-background-color:" + value + ";}");` method the color does not change.I used other method setColor(value),but the same result,and the color does not change.

**This is my java code :**

```
private final ObjectProperty<Paint> Color = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(this, "Color", Paint.valueOf("#0057e7"));

public Paint getColor() {
    return Color.get();
}

public void setColor(Paint value) {

    Color.set(value);
    /*When the user change the property value ,it was sending for make chainging in css*/
    changeColor(value);//send changed value

}

public ObjectProperty ColorProperty() {
    return Color;
}

private static final String USER_AGENT_STYLESHEET = superfx.SuperFx.class.getResource("/stylesheets/style.css").toExternalForm();
private static final String DEFALUT_STYLE_CLASS = "super-fx-qntm-progress-bar";

@Override
public String getUserAgentStylesheet() {
    return USER_AGENT_STYLESHEET;
}     

public SuperFXFQProgressBar() {
    defaultStyle();
    idenfinite();

}

public SuperFXFQProgressBar(double progress) {

    super(progress);
    defaultStyle();
    idenfinite();

}

private void defaultStyle() {

    this.setMinHeight(10);
    this.setPrefHeight(10);
    getStylesheets().add(USER_AGENT_STYLESHEET);
    getStyleClass().add(DEFALUT_STYLE_CLASS);

}

private void idenfinite() {
    setProgress(ProgressBar.INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
}

private void changeSpeed(double value) {
    this.setStyle("\n"
            + "    -fx-indeterminate-bar-animation-time:" + value + ";");
}

/*My problem here*/

private void changeColor(Paint value) {
     /*How can i change the bar color from here*/
    this.setStyle("\n"
            + "    .bar {-fx-background-color:" + value + ";}"); /*this line does not five any effect*/

}
```

**This is my css:**

```
.super-fx-qntm-progress-bar {

    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-indeterminate-bar-animation-time:1.0;
    -fx-indeterminate-bar-flip:true;
    -fx-indeterminate-bar-escape:true;
    -fx-indeterminate-bar-length:10;
    -fx-min-height:5;
}

.super-fx-qntm-progress-bar .track{

    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-border-radius:20;
    -fx-background-radius:20;

}

.super-fx-qntm-progress-bar .bar { 

    -fx-background-color: #0057e7;
    -fx-background-insets: 1 1 1 3, 1 1 1 1, 1 1 2 3; 
    -fx-border-radius:50;
    -fx-background-radius:50;


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a "looked-up color" for your progress bar:

```css
.super-fx-qntm-progress-bar {

    -bar-color: #0057e7;
    /* existing code ... */
}
```

and then use it for the color for the bar:

```css
.super-fx-qntm-progress-bar .bar { 

    -fx-background-color: -bar-color ;
    -fx-background-insets: 1 1 1 3, 1 1 1 1, 1 1 2 3; 
    -fx-border-radius:50;
    -fx-background-radius:50;


}
```

Then essntially all you need in your Java code is

```
this.setStyle("-bar-color: "+value+";");
```

However, you can't simply call `toString()` on the `Paint` object: you need to format it appropriately. So do something like:

```
private String formatColor(Color c) {
    int r = (int) (255 * c.getRed());
    int g = (int) (255 * c.getGreen());
    int b = (int) (255 * c.getBlue());
    return String.format("#%02x%02x%02x", r, g, b);
}
```

and then

```
this.setStyle("-bar-color: "+formatColor((Color)value)+";");
```

Comment: Perfect answer .Thank you @James_D.

Answer (score -1):

**You should know that:**

> css styles can come from style sheets or inline styles. Style sheets
>   are loaded from the URLs specified in the getStylesheets property of
>   the Scene object. If the scene‑graph contains a Control, a default
>   user agent style sheet is loaded. Inline styles are specified via the
>   Node setStyle API. Inline styles are analogous to the style="..."
>   attribute of an HTML element. Styles loaded from a Scene's style
>   sheets take precedence over selectors from the user agent style sheet.
>   Inline styles take precedence over styles originating elsewhere. The
>   precedence order of style selectors can be modified using "!important"
>   in a style declaration.

**What does mean ?**

It means you can not access to selectors by using `setStyle ("selector { property:value"}` ,we add only properties and values in this method ,if your read the javadoc of setStyle you will find that the parameter in this method represent css style of node ,and in your case you need use `lookup()` to search the inner element (.bar ) :

```
Node bar = this.lookup(".bar");
```

By using this code we acces to  bar element of progressbar  after that we add our style.

```
   bar.setStyle("-fx-background-color:" + value);
```

But i see that you get `Paint value` from `Color property`

```
private void changeColor(Paint value) {
     /*How can i change the bar color from here*/
    this.setStyle("\n"
            + "    .bar {-fx-background-color:" + value + ";}"); /*this line does not five any effect*/

}
```

,and i guess you will have a problem of values because  if you check [Color documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/paint/Color.html) and [Paint documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/paint/Paint.html) and when i tested a `Paint value`  of this line `Paint.valueOf("#0057e7")` i found the result is : `0x0057e7ff` ,it means each time your method return value begin with `0x` and css can not understand this value according to [CSS GUIDE](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) so you should replace `0x` with `#` like this :

```
   bar.setStyle("-fx-background-color:" + value.toString().replace("0x", "#"));
```

Try read all content of [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#intropublicapi) to uderstand the "JavaFX Cascading Style Sheets".

Comment: The documentation for `Color.toString()` tells you not to rely on it having any particular implementation.

Comment: @James_D i did not understand you

Comment: You are assuming the `toString()` method will always have that format. The documentation explicitly tells you not to assume that: *"This method is intended to be used only for informational purposes. The content and format of the returned string might vary between implementations. The returned string might be empty but cannot be null."* Your code completely ignores this and assume the returned string will be a particular format.

Comment: You are right ,because `toString()` might change and it has not a fixed format to use it.